# Comparing two groups with unequal sizes?

Tags: r, t-test

I'm writing my thesis on people's attitude. The problem is, I have way more female (75%) than male (25%). I wanted to run an analysis on the different attitude between men and women, but I'm not sure which test to use, since T-test would require the 2 groups to be more or less similar sizes and variance. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your response variable fulfills the [assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#Assumptions) made for a t-test (normality of sample mean etc.) and your only concern is that your two groups are different in size and/or variance, then you can use [Welch's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test), which takes care of exactly those concerns while addressing the same issue, namely whether the means are statistically different or not.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Cross Validated!

Actually, there is no reason why you shouldn't perform a mean comparison test. Equal sample size and varaince are not a requirement.

You may want to check [this](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm) to see how it can be done (unknown means and unknown standard deviations)